# Angular2 How to go back in a RouteConfig

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, routeconfig

I made a simple test to practice the RouteConfig feature and I don't know how to go back to the main component from the children component. My plunker is:

```
plnkr.co/edit/25DCfUADQZJb2XMjb0hW?p=preview
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I had a problem with the Plunker. Chrome Aw, snap!ed every time I changed something. One issue is that the initial page is somewhat invalid. There is no default route selected. (`useAsDefault: true)` I wonder why this didn't produce an error. I think you should split the `/` route and the `/...` route and make one the default. Then navigating to any route should work. When you navigate to a root route use `/RouteName` instead of just `RouteName`.

Comment: I made several changes based on your answer and the component didn't load. Finally, I left it unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

I think it may help you. Just try it.

```
this._location.back();
```

Comment: I changed that part in the function located inside the children component and the test has a strange behaviour. http://plnkr.co/edit/25DCfUADQZJb2XMjb0hW?p=preview